# How to separate two citation call-outs with a semicolon and not wit a comma?

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm using the `natbib` package to create citation call-outs in latex. When introducing multiple citations using `\citep{citation1, citation2}`, I cannot seperate them by a semicolon because it conflicts with the `\setcitestyle` option. How can I fix this?

Example:

text editor:

```
This is some example text where i try to refer to \citep{albus1971theory,ito1984cerebellum} their work.
```

current output:

```
This is some example text where i try to refer to (Novello et al., 2022, Teune et al., 2000) their work.
```

desired output:

```
This is some example text where i try to refer to (Novello et al., 2022; Teune et al., 2000) their work.
```

my code:

```
%% preamble %%
\documentclass{dissertation}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

%%  main file %%
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
{\footnotesize\bibliography{dissertation}}
```

entries in the file `dissertation.bib`:

```
@article{teune2000topography,
  title={Topography of cerebellar nuclear projections to the brain stem in the rat},
  author={Teune, TM and Van der Burg, J and Van Der Moer, J and Voogd, Jan and Ruigrok, TJH},
  journal={Progress in brain research},
  volume={124},
  pages={141--172},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{novello2022systematic,
  title={A systematic review of direct outputs from the cerebellum to the brainstem and diencephalon in mammals},
  author={Novello, Manuele and Bosman, Laurens WJ and De Zeeuw, Chris I},
  journal={The Cerebellum},
  pages={1--30},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Springer}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch hi, I updated the question now with code as well...

Comment: Your code is still not compilable. Please take a look at how to prepare a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Off-topic: Don't lump initials together. I.e., do write `Ruigrok, T J H` instead of `Ruigrok, TJH`, `Teune, T M` instead of `Teune, TM`, and so on. Why? Left to its own devices, BibTeX has no way of knowing that the author with surname `Ruigrok` has three given names, with initials "T", "J", and "H" rather than just one given name that happens to be spelled "TJH".

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

> I cannot seperate [the citation call-outs] by a semicolon because it conflicts with the `\setcitestyle` option

This claim is a *non sequitur*. Just because you're currently running

```
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
```

does *not* mean that you cannot set additional options. I suggest you add the option `citesep={;}` to specify your preferred citation call-out separator. Incidentally, you may also want to simplify the options `open={(},close={)}` to just `round`.

What I don't understand about your posting is that you seem to want to enforce what's actually the default behavior of the `natbib` citation management package. Does your code -- possibly the mysterious `dissertation` document class? -- contain `\bibpunct` and/or `\setcitestyle` directives that override the `citesep={;}` default?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % I don't have the 'dissertation' document class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{dissertation.bib} % create bib file

@article{teune2000topography,
  title={Topography of cerebellar nuclear projections to the brain stem in the rat},
  author={Teune, T M and Van der Burg, J and Van Der Moer, J and Voogd, Jan and Ruigrok, T J H},
  journal={Progress in Brain Research},
  volume={124},
  pages={141--172},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{novello2022systematic,
  title={A systematic review of direct outputs from the cerebellum to the brainstem and diencephalon in mammals},
  author={Novello, Manuele and Bosman, Laurens W J and De Zeeuw, Chris I},
  journal={The Cerebellum},
  pages={1--30},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Springer}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,
              round,
              citesep={;} % that's the default, actually
             }
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citep{teune2000topography,novello2022systematic}
\bibliography{dissertation}
\end{document}
```